# django accessing uploaded files in model custom save, best practice?

Tags: python, django, models, filefield, imagefield

Ive recently been experiementing with using django

I want to be able to run an uploaded file through imagemagick on the model save function, I realised this wasn't possible due to the file not being available till the instance had been saved

I've got it working were the save is called at the start which then allows access to the uploaded file then re saves once its populated the other fields

Is there a better way to achieve this? it just kinda feels wrong calling the save function twice

```
class uploadedFiles(models.Model):
orignal_image = models.FileField(upload_to='userimages/')
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)


def __unicode__(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    return "%s uploaded by %s" % (self.orignal_image.path, self.user) 

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    super(uploadedFiles, self).save()
    s = ''
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(['identify', '-verbose', self.orignal_image.path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cmd.stdout:
        s += line
    self.description = s
    super(uploadedFiles, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use the imaging library functions to collect image metadata. Then you just have to read the image data from the `FileStorage` instance of the image field. Just check for the [documentation of file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/). Also, when using Django's `ImageField`, it checks the uploaded file to see if is a valid image file, check the code for `ImageField` as a baseline to obtain more info about an image.

I would define an `clean` method to the model, this will get called just before calling the model's `save` method. In `clean`, then check the data stream of the image field with the PIL functions to obtain the metadata (or whatever library you want to use for this, as long as it accepts a data stream, **not** a physical file) and then fill the description field with the metadata.

Using the Django's Storage API is better, so you can extract metadata from files stored in the cloud (like Amazon S3), rather than just those stored in a local filesystem, making the code much more portable across deployments.

Answer (score -1):

Use Django's `pre_save` signal ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), see also [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) in Django's documentation):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from myapp.models import MyModel

def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
pre_save.connect(do_something, sender=MyModel)
```

Django will now call `do_something` before saving `MyModel` objects.